# Want null value in SQL date fields when checkbox clicked

Tags: sql-server, date, ms-access, checkbox, vba

I have a access frontend to a SQL database.  On the form, I have a checkbox (All Day).  When I check the checkbox, I want it to put null values in two time fields (BeginTimeOff and EndTimeOff).  In SQL, the All Day field is a yes/no field, and the date fields are set to accept nulls.

I've tried (on beforeupdate and afterupdate):

```
'Me.txtStartTime.Value = ""
'Me.txtEndTime.Value = ""
```

This works in a new record, but not when editing an existing record - it put 12:00 AM in the date fields.

I also tried:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblWorkHours SET BeginTimeOff = Null", dbSeeChanges
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblWorkHours SET EndTimeOff = Null", dbSeeChanges
```

Also, tried it without the dbSeeChanges at end of each.  Either way, this gives me a write conflict error and does not save the changes for the yes/no field, and puts 12:00 AM in each of the date fields.

For day and time calculations, it is important that it clears out the date fields (nulls) if All Day is checked.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Later...
Here is everything I tried so far:

```
'Me.txtStartTime.Value = ""
'Me.txtEndTime.Value = ""

'Me.txtStartTime.Value = System.DbNull.Value
'Me.txtEndTime.Value = System.DbNull.Value

'Me.txtStartTime.Value = Null
'Me.txtEndTime.Value = Null

'CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblWorkHours SET BeginTimeOff = System.DbNull.Value", dbSeeChanges
'CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblWorkHours SET EndTimeOff = System.DbNull.Value", dbSeeChanges
```

None of these work.  Any other ideas, please?  I am completely stumped

Comment: Can you open `tblWorkHours` directly in DataSheet View and edit the `BeginTimeOff` value in an existing record?

Comment: This worked - I had a typo. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.txtEndTime.Value = DBNull.Value
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of explanation to your answer? A lone-line code change may be what they need, but does not help them understand why this is the correct solution.

Comment: you need to pass it with the parameter as value. or try this one System.DbNull.Value

Comment: i mean. CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblWorkHours SET BeginTimeOff = '"+System.DbNull.Value+"'", dbSeeChanges

Comment: I think I'm not reading or seeing it correctly.  Here's what I see:  CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblWorkHours SET BeginTimeOff = '" + System.DbNull.Value + "'", dbSeeChanges       Is this correct?

Comment: I tried: CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblWorkHours SET BeginTimeOff = System.DbNull.Value ", dbSeeChanges   and I'm getting Run time error 3061 - too few parameters.  Expected 1.